# Graphics stop working after calling ExitBootServices()

Tags: bootloader, firmware, uefi

I'm trying to write a printf function to use after exiting uefi boot services, and of course to do it i have to access the frame buffer. Now.. as you can see from the code below, i save the gop frame buffer address before calling exit_bs() and then i try to draw a line using that address, but it doesn't work. **Note that if i run that loop before exit_bs() it works as expected**, is it maybe because the frame buffer changes or something similar?

```
struct video_init init_info;
efi_gop_t *gop = NULL;
efi_guid_t gopGuid = EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL_GUID;
efi_status_t status = BS -> LocateProtocol(&gopGuid, NULL, (void **) &gop);

if (!EFI_ERROR(status) && gop) {
    ST -> ConOut -> Reset(ST -> ConOut, 0);
    ST -> StdErr -> Reset(ST -> StdErr, 0);
        
    init_info.video_height = gop -> Mode -> Information -> VerticalResolution;
    init_info.video_width = gop -> Mode -> Information -> HorizontalResolution;
    init_info.video_pitch = sizeof(unsigned int) * gop -> Mode -> Information -> PixelsPerScanLine;
    init_info.frame_buffer = (char *) gop -> Mode -> FrameBufferBase;
} else {
    return false;
}

if (exit_bs()) {
    fail("failed to exit boot services");
}

//this is the loop i'm referring to
for (int i = 0; i < init_info.video_height; i++) {
    *((uint32_t *)(init_info.frame_buffer + init_info.video_pitch * i + 4 * i)) = 0xFFFF00;
}
```

As you may have noticed i'm using posix-uefi framework, and i run this on a virtualbox vm.

Comment: After looking at the source code to the `exit_bs` function, I'm curious how that function would ever work; it always passes NULL for the memory map arg to `GetMemoryMap`. It's possible that the loop is never executed if placed after the `exit_bs` call. Also note that `exit_bs` calls `__stdio_cleanup` at the start, which means stdout likely no longer works after it returns.

Comment: In fact, if the call to `GetMemoryMap` succeeds, the loop exits without ever calling `ExitBootServices`; so I'd chalk it up to a bug in posix-uefi.